# Change Hadoop HDFS name of file

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I want to change the automatically saved filename of a HDFS block on a cluster. So when I upload a file to the HDFS and it'll divided into blocks, they get generated names with several numbers.
I searched the code but couldn't find it.

It should be somewhere in the java code, not a configuration file, right?

Can someone may tell me in which classes this creation or definition of the filename happens?

Thanks a lot!

edit:

Ok found it.

```
FSNameSystem.randBlockId.nextLong()
```

Comment: Which files are you talking about? When you just upload a file to HDFS it doesn't divide it into blocks or anything! Are you talking about running a hadoop job and it's output coming with files named like part-r-0000, part-r-0001 etc?

Comment: For example, I copied a local 200 MB file to my local hadoop system. This file was divided into 64 MB pieces and have filenames like blk_-3782870051006427006. What I mean is this number after blk_*. I saw that the constructor of the Block class has a blkid attribute, but I'm still looking for the method that invokes it. Is it correct that the NameNode assigns a block id?

Comment: Yes the namenode assigns the block ID's, but what's your requirement to change the naming of these files - the name node handles mapping these names and multiple files to a 'user-friendly' name - these 'idx-3123890....' names are not exposed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it.

```
FSNameSystem.randBlockId.nextLong()
```